# How to find/delete a string value in the registry based on its value

Tags: batch-file, registry

I am trying to write a .reg file that would take a given key, and search for a string value based on its contents, and then delete it.
For example:

```
[path]
"a"="b"
"z"="y"
"foo"="bar"
```

And somehow delete the value "foo" by knowing either "bar" or a substring of that.
Is this possible?
Would I need to do this in a .bat script (which is fine, btw)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this in a BAT file

```
SET KEY=HKLM\Software\MySoftware\Path
SET VALUE=BAR
for /F "tokens=1,*" %%a in ('REG QUERY "%KEY%" ^| findstr /I /C:"%VALUE%"') do (echo REG DELETE "%KEY%" /v %%a)
```

and after extra careful testing remove the ECHO.