# Search and Delete registry keys based on ProductName value

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, registry

I am trying to build a batch file that will search a group of registry keys located at **`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products\(random hex code)`**  with the goal of deleting keys that match the criteria.

The criteria is that the value of the ProductName == *SQL*

My code:

```
Set RegDirectory=HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products
Set regArray= an empty array

regquery RegDirectory for keys containing string "SQL" then addTo regArray

set keyToDelete=
:deleteAKey
if not keToDelete== "check if array is empty" (
    do reg delete keyToDelete
    GOTO deleteAKey
)
```

And then I need to repeat the process for **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\`** which MAY be slightly different as those hex codes are {} bracketed.

Closest thing I've been able to find is this article
[How to find/delete a string value in the registry based on its value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323388/how-to-find-delete-a-string-value-in-the-registry-based-on-its-value)
But that doesn't seem to search values of keys within a group of keys, just values in a key. I've found other things, but they are not .bat files, usually C++ or VB.  I'd prefer something .bat since I'll need to use it in environments where the system stability doesn't always allow .NET to run.

EDIT:

After reading comments, I am trying to only pull the first value I come across, delete it, and rerun the query.  My first problem with this is that I seem to not understand the syntax for REG QUERY.  I think the following command should return only the registries with SQL in the value ProductName, but I get a vague message about bad syntax.
ERROR: Invalid syntax.
Type **`REG QUERY /?`** for usage.
Does anyone have any clues as to what I am typing wrong?

Syntax I'm using is found here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742028%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

```
reg query HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products [/v ProductName ] [/s] [/f SQL] [/d] [/t REG_SZ]
```

Comment: Why do you need an `Array`?  Why not read -->find-->delete-->read ...?

Comment: I suppose it doesn't need to be an array, but it needs to store multiple values as SQL puts about 10 registry keys in that folder.

Comment: Actually, now that you mention it, I suppose I could build it recursively so that it deletes the first one it finds and then reruns until it doesn't find one.  Then catch the error and continue running?

Comment: What is your Windows version?

Comment: I'm hoping to make this run in both windows 7 and 8.  Though I'm slowly being convinced by a friend to scrap the project in .bat and try in VBscript instead.
I'll need a way for .bat to handle an array and execute a command against each value in the array. 
Apparently Batch files are not known for smooth handling of arrays.

Answer (score 2):

try this to find key values with "SQL":

```
 for /f "delims=" %%a in ('reg query HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products') do for /f "delims=" %%b in ('reg query "%%~a"') do echo %%b|find /i "SQL"
```